# Why doesn't Eclipse always register Ctrl+z in the following piece of code

Tags: java, eclipse, null, ctrl

I'm writing a Java program and I have this section of code in the initialization part of my code:

```
while (container!=null) {
    sb.append(container);
    container = reader.readLine();
}
System.out.println("go")
```

When I run the program, type some strings in standard input and when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>(I'm working in Windows) it doesn't print "go", basically it's like it never registered. I noticed this happens when first couple of input strings are empty e.g., this input will work:

```
input

that

works
```

(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>)

This input won't work:

```
input

that

doesn't work
```

(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: TextField object does not return `null` it returns `""`. That's why it doesn't work.

Comment: @VighaneshGursale TextField object? I'm not really experienced in Java, could you, please, explain further? I tried changing the loop condition to `while(!container.equals(""))` but that gave me a null pointer exeption when I entered Ctrl+Z...

Comment: @Zltantan try to print the textfield content with your previous condition. If you got something different then I can tell you. Cause right you've not posted whole code so I can assume that something is getting stored in `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Show us some code that can be compiled so we know exactly what you are doing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Can you not try:

```
while(container != null && !container.equals("")) {
    sb.append(container);
    container = reader.readLine();
}
System.out.println("go")
```